# OneNote Options

Tags: microsoft-onenote

So I have these OneNote notebooks up on office.live.com. From there I sync a few laptops and, when on a PC without OneNote installed, I can work directly with my notebooks in a browser.

I'd LOVE to be able to work with my notebooks from my Android browser or in some other fashion.

I'm aware of MobilNoter. As near as I can tell, it doesn't leverage the live.com storage that I'm already syncing to. If that's true then it isn't the answer I'm after.

Anyone else using OneNote with or on Android? If so, how?

*(Please don't suggest I switch to Evernote. It is nice, but it ain't OneNote!)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft OneNote now has an official app for Android. You can edit and sync up to 500 notes.

Answer (score 2):

Mobilenoter SE will sync with Skydrive (office.live.com) but is currently read only.  For a couple of weeks in early April, Firefox on Android worked on Office.live.com directly, but M$ changed something and now you can not edit your OneNote files online in any Android browser I have tried (and I have tried almost all of them).

Very frustrating.

Alan

Answer (score 1):

I've followed this issue, and I'm quite sure Mobilnoter is the best that can be done until MS comes out with an Android version of OneNote. Unlike a Mac version, that move seems inevitable, since many Windows users are on Android.

Comment: I'd like to be wrong, but I'm pretty sure that mobilenoter doesn't use the office.live.com site for syncing (like I do for all my PCs).